# Apply VBA to Multiple Sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to apply the below code to 26 out of the total 35 sheets. I can't seem to figure it out. Currently the macros is setup to apply to all sheets but I need to either edit it to exclude the eight tabs that it will not apply to, or edit it to apply to the 26 sheets themselves. I do plan on hiding the 26 tabs as they feed into a summary sheet so would this affect the formula?

For context, in each worksheet that requires the sort, columns B to Q have data and I'm sorting by ticker in column C (ascending). Any thoughts here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
 Sub SortAllSheets()

  Dim WS As Worksheet

  ActiveSheet.Range("B1:Q1").Select

  Selection.Copy
  On Error Resume Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For Each WS In Worksheets

    WS.Range("B2:Q500").Sort Key1:=WS.Columns("C"), Order1:=xlAscending

  Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: I would probably try using [`Select Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/select-case-statement) on the sheet names

Comment: Why don't you share how we could identify the sheets? The 9 or the 26? What do they have in common? For example, they could start with, contain or end with a substring. Here is a [link to my most recent `Select Case` example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69765020).

Comment: Thank you for this. So each worksheet is titled by the broader investment account identifier - a three to 7 digit alphabetic code. On the overall summary sheet, I'm using some indirect formulas to pull based off one of the 2 sheets, depending on which code is selected from a drop down. The 26 worksheets are completely identical in terms of columns, but differ in number of rows depending on holdings and the actual sheet title itself.

Comment: It's maybe easiest to write the 9 sheet names (not to be processed) or their code names to a comma-separated list. Could you share the list so I could post an example?

Answer (score 0):

What I would likely do, especially if the logic is going to get complicated, is use regex to match sheet names, and skip if the regex doesn't match (or vice versa, whichever is easier to generate the pattern for):

```
Set parser = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
parser.ignorecase = True
parser.pattern = "your pattern"

For Each WS In Worksheets

  if parser.test(WS.name) then
  
    >> YOUR CODE

  end if

Next
```

or you can use a line label to skip, if you don't like the extra indent from the IF (although a lot of people hate goto):

```
Set parser = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
parser.ignorecase = True
parser.pattern = "your pattern"

For Each WS In Worksheets

  if NOT parser.test(WS.name) then goto skip:
  
  >> YOUR CODE

skip:
Next
```